# Telegram. Почему загрузка файла выполняется только со 2-го раза?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Обработчик события отправки пользователем фото боту приведен ниже.

Проблема в следующем - если файл отправляется пользователем первый раз, то сохранения ботом файла в массив не происходит. Если файл из клиента отправляю еще раз, обработчик отлично отрабатывает, файл получается ботом и сохраняется.

Используется библиотека от MrRoundRobin. Основа работы с файлами взята оттуда же. Что не так в коде?

```
private async Task PhotoMessageHandler(Message m)
{
    if (m.Type != MessageType.PhotoMessage)
        return;

    var p = m.Photo.Last();

    await Bot.WriteChatAsync(m.Chat.Id, $"загружено изображение {m.Photo.Length} байт");

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var file = await _bot.GetFileAsync(p.FileId, ms);

        var attachName = p.FilePath.Split('/').Last();
        var attachData = ms.ToArray();
        var attach = new ReqAttach(attachName, attachData);

        await Bot.WriteChatAsync(m.Chat.Id, $"Добавлено изображение {p.FileSize} байт");
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой строчке ошибка? Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Локально код не выполнить, он публикуется и работает на удаленном сервере. Обернутый в try/catch тоже ошибку не вывел.

Comment: Тогда добавляйте отладочный вывод на каждую строчку.

Comment: какая версия библиотеки?

Comment: Не весь код, поэтому не всё понятно, что Вы делаете с переменной _file_ и что такое _ReqAttach()_, например. 

     `await Bot.WriteChatAsync(m.Chat.Id, $"загружено изображение {m.Photo.Length} байт");`
Тут ошибка, т.к. объект `Photo` - это массив размеров одного изображения. Хотя тут   

    `await Bot.WriteChatAsync(m.Chat.Id, $"Добавлено изображение {p.FileSize} байт");`
вроде всё верно сделано.

Comment: Дайте больше кода

Comment: NuGet пакет, самый свежий. Версия в нем 10.4.0

Comment: ReqAttach - объект, хранящий имя файла и байтовый массив его содержимого.
Переменная file забывается, так как в параметрах указан Stream destination (ms), в который заливается содержимое. Мне нужно только это.

Из кода обработчика убрана обертка try/catch, для улучшения читабельности, и строчка сохранения ReqAttach в коллекцию. Всё.
Так что это весь код обработчика. И он работает на повторной загруженном изображении. Т.е. формально он правильный. Наверно. Либо я чего-то не вижу.

Comment: @Anatol _Тут ошибка, т.к. объект Photo - это массив размеров одного изображения._ Это не совсем так. Массив типа `PhotoSize` - наследника `Bot.Types.File`

Comment: *Это не совсем так* - Вы явно не понимаете, о чём говорите. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize Что даёт длина этого массива?

Comment: *NuGet пакет, самый свежий. Версия в нем 10.4.0* - это последняя стабильная версия, есть уже 11.1 beta3. А примеры на гитхабе вообще позапрошлого года, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: И вообще эту всю информацию лучше добавлять к вопросу, а не постить в комментах

Comment: Вопрос неполный. Нет результатов отладки, нет результатов работы. Возможно, если добавите эту информацию, то вопрос отпадёт сам собой. А так - посмотрите в сторону  `var file = await _bot.GetFileAsync(p.FileId, ms);` - предполагаю, что тут нужен синхронный код.

Comment: _core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize Что даёт длина этого массива?_ мне это дает количество переданных файлов. согласен, выглядит как логическая ошибка. НО это отладочный вывод в чат. на логику и тем более на ошибку - не влияет никак

Comment: @Anatol _ А так - посмотрите в сторону var file = await _bot.GetFileAsync(p.FileId, ms); - предполагаю, что тут нужен синхронный код_ С какой целью? И что это даст. Если GetFileAsync внутри весь асинхронный.

Comment: Ну продолжайте ждать тогда.

Answer (score 0):

**p** - это элемент массива **PhotoSize**, у него нет поля **FilePath**. Метод **GetFileAsync** как раз для того и нужен, чтобы получить путь. Следовательно, нужно делать так:

```
var attachName = file.FilePath.Split('/').Last(); //p.FilePath.Split('/').Last();
```

В противном случае выбрасывается **NullReferenceException**. А со второго раза отрабатывает потому, что при повторной отправке файла он не грузится заново, а берётся с серверов телеграма и у него уже известен путь.

Comment: да, p вместо file это ошибка. но при повторной загрузке путь всё равно не передается для последнего элемента. так что даже без этой строчки проблема не решилась.

для некоторых изображений обработчик вообще не вызывается - похоже, глотается исключение где-то в самой библиотеке еще при разборе. поведение воспроизводится.